# JodaTime difference between plusHours and plusDays for Daylight Savings Time

Tags: java, jodatime, dst

According to the JodaTime Javadoc, plusHours and plusDays both handle DST adjustments when adding time to a date.  However, from my tests adding a days worth of hours vs adding 1 day gives a different result.  Can someone explain to me why the following code gives the output below?

Code:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
Date date = format.parse("2014-11-01T02:00:00.000-0700");

System.out.println("origDate:  " + date);
System.out.println("plusDays:  " + new DateTime(date).plusDays(1).toDate());
System.out.println("plusHours: " + new DateTime(date).plusHours(24).toDate());
```

Output:

```
origDate:  Sat Nov 01 02:00:00 PDT 2014
plusDays:  Sun Nov 02 02:00:00 PST 2014
plusHours: Sun Nov 02 01:00:00 PST 2014
```

Comment: I just tried your code. Basically copy/pasted, using joda-time 2.4, here is the output:
origDate:  Sat Nov 01 10:00:00 CET 2014
plusDays:  Sun Nov 02 10:00:00 CET 2014
plusHours: Sun Nov 02 10:00:00 CET 2014

Comment: You are not using pure Joda-Time, but also `SimpleDateFormat` and `java.util.Date.toString()`. Why? This just adds an extra error source when evaluating your code example.

Comment: @mattias - The use of `toDate` and `SimpleDateFormat` here are applying the local time zone.  The OP is running in US Pacific Time.

Comment: @MattJohnson: Thx for clarifying. Timezone handling's always tricky :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not all local days have 24 hours. Assuming you are working in the US Pacific time zone, there are 25 hours on that particular day, due to the fall-back daylight saving time transition.

Calling `plusHours(24)` adds an exact duration of 24 hours elapsed time.

Calling `plusDays(1)` increments the calendar day, even if the day is not exactly 24 hours.